# How to call a container, running on a virtual machine, from a Windows browser?

Tags: windows, docker, boot2docker

I have Windows 7 operating system and have set up **Docker**. Docker starts on the virtual machine. I create some containers on Docker and test them on the command line, for example:

```
curl localhost:9200
```

Now I want to test this container from a Windows browser

```
http://localhost:9200
```

How do I call the container, which is running on a virtual machine, from a Windows browser?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have 'published' the service to port 9200, just use the IP address of the VM instead of `localhost`.  To get that address, you can inspect your VM setup, or use the `boot2docker` command:

```
boot2docker ip
```

Then, insert that address where I have the 'x's here in your browser:

```
http://x.x.x.x:9200
```

Answer (score 0):

Or map published IP address from docker container running inside boot2docker like this:

```
boot2docker ssh -L 0.0.0.0:9200:localhost:9200
```

That way, you (and others that can access your computer) can acccess it on both of the following links:

```
http://localhost:9200
http://<host_machine_ip>:9200
```